# Simple function does not work within if-statement

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a somewhat nested JSON file:

```
{
  "name": "1370",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Position X",
      "value": -1
    },
    {...}
  ]
  "matches": [
    {
      "certainty": 100,
      "match": {
        "name": "1370",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Position X",
                "value": -1
          },
          {...}
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to display it using a modified [Collapsible Tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083). I want to display the "match" and "certainty" when hovering the corresponding node. I've used the [simple tooltip example](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/1016860) for this.

Now I have something like this:

```
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      ...
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          if (d.matches) {
            return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
              .text( function(d) { return d.name; } );
          }
       } )
      ...
      ;
```

I'm just using d.name for testing. I want to write a more complex function later. But that doesn't work at all. I get a tooltip, but it's empty (or contains the default value). The point which I don't understand is, that the following works:

```
if (d.matches) {
  return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
    .text( d.name );
}
```

Therefore it seems to me, that a function doesn't work at this point. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Way too much nested logic. It's not clear to me at all what is being returned to what. For debugging, remove the condition `if (d.matches)`. It's not relevant. Why are you returning `d.name`? Shouldn't you just use it like you did in the second example? `.text( d.name );`

Comment: What do you expect the parameter "d" to be in your "mouseover" handler?  It'll be an Event object, regardless.

Comment: @Pointy This is an event handler in the `d3` context. Hence, the `d` in the `mouseover`'s handler will be the `data` associated with that node.

Comment: Ah sorry; d3 always confuses me :)

Comment: @m59 As I mentioned returning d.name by a function is just for first testing. I need a much more complex function later. In the end I want a tooltip containing all data from the 'matches'-branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake you are making is that in your call to jQuery's .text() method, you are passing in a function, but what you want to pass in is the return value of that function. In order to do this, you simply need to invoke the function you are passing in with the argument it expects:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
  ...
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      if (d.matches) {
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
          .text( function(d) { return d.name; }(d) );
      }
   } )
  ...
  ;
```

notice how the function is invoked using (d) after it is declared

Answer (score 0):

The `tooltip` in the [linked example](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/1016860) does not have any data associated with it. Hence, if you try to use the [`text` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-text) with an accessor, it cannot get any data.

My guess is that you do not want to take data from the `tooltip`, but instead work with the data passed by `D3` to your `mouseover` event:

```js
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
  ...
  .on("mouseover", function(d) { // <-- This is the data passed by D3, associated to your node.
      if (d.matches) {
        var newName = computeNameFromData(d);
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
          .text( newName ); // <-- Just pass a string here.
      }
   } )
  ...
  ;
```